# add change() event to an existing click() function without triggering the first event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery `click()` function and I need to add the `change()` event for another element (that must only trigger the `change()` event).

How can I combine it, but make this extra element only trigger one of the two events?

```
$('body').on('click change', '.click-1, .click-2, :checkbox, .change', function()
```

I added the change event and the change class. Also for the checkboxes, are they going to trigger the two events? (could it be a problem?).

Is there any way to make the element only trigger that event and not the `click()`?

I just need to find a way to not repeat the same code (50 lines) twice.

EDIT: Fix (thanks to @somethinghere):

```
$('body').on('click change', '.click-1, .click-2, :checkbox, .change', function(event) {

    if (event.type == 'click' && $(this).hasClass( 'change' )) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return;
    }

    // more code
});
```

A proper fix should be use `click()` only for the buttons.

Comment: You could check the `event.type` and `preventDefault()` (and `stopImmediatePropagation()` inside your function? I am unsure, but I think the order of your events makes a difference, so if you want your `change` to be evaluated before your `click` (so you can cancel out the click), you should change their order in your `on`...

Comment: Yes! I thought it was going to be more difficult. So I add an if comparing to the event name? Just that? What event needs to be first?

Comment: You will have to see what the event type is (its somewhere in the event object) and then check for it, yes. I think `stopImmediatePropagation` would allow you to cancel out any subsequent events, and if it's the wrong event you could simply skip the code execution? It's hard to see as I don't know what you are trying to do, so I cannot really say what the order should be and how you should skip and cancel, but this can be done.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm trying to add select lists to a search filter with checkboxes, I'm using click for the checkboxes instead of change because there are also more buttons, but now I need the change event for the select elements to trigger the ajax script when the value changes. So I can stop the script with `stopImmediatePropagation` just that? Because there isn't a better way to execute the same code for the buttons, checkboxes and selects?

Comment: I think all Form elements emit a `change` event. If you want to add buttons to that, you could use a `click` and simply check for maybe the tagname opf the target? `event.target.tagName` should be 'INPUT' for every `<input />`, so you could check for that (and `SELECT` of course) and do something else if it's `BUTTON`?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the buttons and checkboxes trigger the click and do the ajax, but the select elements can't trigger it. I select an option from the list but the function is not triggered, I need to use the change event to triger the ajax script with the select lists. But if I just add the change event and the element class, when i click the select to open the list the script is triggered...

Comment: So: `if(event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') triggerClick(); else triggerChange()` - You should not have to rely on a `click` event for checkboxes as they _also_ trigger a change event if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Well, the buttons are really `<a>` tags formatted with css. Yes, you are right, I should only use the click event for the buttons and change event for the rest. Do I just need to add the if at the beginning of the `on()` function?

Comment: Hmm there are many ways to do this: I could make a function and pass it but maybe is better to check the `event.type` but how to check it, to do this properly.

Comment: Just do it and refactor later, thats the best advice i can give!

Comment: Ok, just to know it's working i'm trying the easy way: `if ( event.type == 'click' && $( this ).hasClass( '.in-drop' )) {preventDefault(); stopImmediatePropagation(); return;}` but it's not working...

Comment: `stopImmediatePropagation` is an `event` method, so its `event.stopImm...`, as is `preventDefault`.

Comment: Yes sorry, also `hasClass()` don't need the dot before the classname.

Comment: If I add `:checkbox` selector to the if will the checkboxes only trigger the `change()` event? I don't know if it's triggering twice or the two events at the same time. It's working ok...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, store the function and pass the function as a parameter twice:

```
function yourfunctionname(e) {
   ...
}

$('body').on('click', '.click-1, .click-2', yourfunctionname)
    .on('change', ':checkbox, .change', yourfunctionname);
```

Comment: Yes it's simple and now that I see an example it's better.